# Error when running the Turtlebot_bringup launch file

Tags: ros, turtlebot, groovy-turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to implement 2D slam on an old iRobot Create with a Kinect attached to it.

This is the procedure I am following -

- I have the iRobot Create.
- I install the ros-groovy-brown-driver to be able to connect to the Create.
  I have also installed the turtlebot
  ros package.
- I start roscore. And then I run the
  following command

  rosrun irobot_create_2_1 driver.py cmd_vel:=turtlebot_node/cmd_vel

  The Create plays that music.
  I wish to run the turtlebot_teleop command, but before that I try to run the
  following command

  roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

I get the following errors. Also, if I run the turtlebot_teleop command for keyboard, it gets executed without errors but pressing the keys don't move the bot at all.

> [ERROR] [1386716974.533922230]: filter
> time older than odom message buffer
> [ERROR] [1386716974.555218373]:
> Covariance specified for measurement
> on topic wheelodom is zero  [ERROR]
> [1386716974.616525541]: Covariance
> specified for measurement on topic
> wheelodom is zero  [ERROR]
> [1386716974.633544675]: filter time
> older than odom message buffer Failed
> to open port /dev/ttyUSB0.  Please
> make sure the Create cable is plugged
> into the computer.   [ERROR]
> [1386716974.691582292]: Covariance
> specified for measurement on topic
> wheelodom is zero  [WARN] [WallTime:
> 1386716974.708936] Create : robot not connected yet, sci not available
> [ERROR] [1386716974.733089805]: filter
> time older than odom message buffer
> [ERROR] [1386716974.766284180]:
> Covariance specified for measurement
> on topic wheelodom is zero

Other point to be noted -
The USB port parameter had to be modified to ttyUSB1 instead of ttyUSB0. This was done using the following command -

```
rosparam set /brown/irobot_create_2_1/port /dev/ttyUSB1
```

I think this might be the issue because the parameter isn't set for turtlebot package. I don't know how to change it for the turtlebot package though.

Also, there I can't seem to find, turtlebot_driver anywhere. Shouldn't that have been installed along with the turtlebot package? Edit: I think it's now called create_driver. I have modified the create_driver.py to cahnge ttyUSB0 to ttyUSB1, but still the minimal.launch fails.

What needs to be done in this case?

Is there an alternative to using the turtlebot package to be able to run teleop?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109046/error-when-running-the-turtlebot_bringup-launch-file/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2013-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the issue.

1. When running the command for minimal.launch, there was some kind of clash between the irobot_create_2_1_driver and the create_driver (turtlebot_driver). When I ended irobot_create_2_1_driver command the minimal.launch worked. If anyone knows why this issue between the two please let me know.
2. The minimial.launch was giving trouble because of the  ttyUSB0 issue after this. Solutions for that are already available on answers.ros.org.

Right now, the turtlebot_teleop commands work.

---

Originally posted by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) with karma: 237 on 2013-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0